# Using .lyr files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sld, layer-file

I'm trying to use a publicly available data set (the [Australian National Vegetation Information System](http://environment.gov.au/fed/catalog/search/resource/downloadData.page?uuid=%7B991C36C0-3FEA-4469-8C30-BB56CC2C7772%7D)) in QGIS, but it has been set up for use in ArcGIS (.lyr file).

I tried to convert the file using http://wald.intevation.org/projects/arcmap2sld/ but kept getting an error saying it was an unsupported file type.

I can open the individual data layers directly in QGIS, however, there doesn't seem to be any coherency to the way the data layers are named, and hence I'm not sure what the differences between them are, or whether I'm using the appropriate one for my project.

Can anyone recommend another approach for using the data in QGIS and/or advise on how to interpret the data package?

Before asking I reviewed:

- [this](https://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/arcgis-lyr-files-and-qgis-qlr-files) article on the difference between .lyr files and .qlr files,
  and
- [this](https://tutel.me/c/gis/questions/3755/converting+arcgis+layer+style+to+styled+layer+descriptor+sld+file) question about converting .lyr files

I also looked at [the slyr tool](https://github.com/nyalldawson/slyr/blob/master/README.md), but couldn't figure out how to install it (sorry, newbie here!)